# Problem with id tweet, when tweet has been delete (Jtwitter)

Tags: java, status, tweets, jtwitter

My code is:

```
for(int i=0;i<listTweetId.size();i++){    
     if((status = twitter.getStatus(listTweetId.get(i)))!=null){
      ...
```

My problem is that exist some tweetId into listTweetId that are Id of tweets deleted and I don't know how it verify, because my if not works for this case. Finally in this case it spears a error, that is follows :

```
Exception in thread "main" winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException$E404: 
    Not Found HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
    {"error":"No status found with that ID.","request":"/1/statuses/show/112779914381492224.json?include_entities=1&"}
```

P.S.: Tweets are not empty

Answer (score 2):

I'm not *entirely* sure what your question is, but if the issue is that getting the status for a non-existent tweet throws an exception, you need to wrap that part in a try/catch to avoid dropping out of the loop.